# Syntax for scope value into other scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

With angularjs, what is the correct way to get in the view :

```
{{votedList[{{song.Radio.idSong}}].voted}}
```

give `Error: [$parse:syntax]`

song.Radio.idSong is a integer, getting into a ng-repeat
votedList is a scope array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one:

```
{{votedList[song.Radio.idSong].voted}}
```

The double brackets in a view are used for rendering an [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), therefore you don't need to interpolate again inside the expression.

Also, [scopes inherit the properties of their ancestors](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies) (except for [isolated scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)) so, as long as you are using that expression inside a scope that has visibility for that property, you are good to go.